# WCF without ASPNetCompatibility mode getting hold of weboperationcontext

Tags: wcf

Although i know that WCF is transport-agnostic and without setting AspNetCompatibility mode i never get the HTTP context. What all values can i get from weboperation context.

I my application we have been using ASMX and by default we get hold of httpcontext.current with that but we decided to move to WCF. But if we move to WCF and set  AspNetCompatibility mode(to get hold of httpcontext) its same as calling asmx service. Is there a way i can pass some values from client(JQuery) for the first time and then set WebOperationContext and use it for the subsequent request.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to support sessions in the WCF service ?. Is that what you mean ? WCF supports sessions altough is not a good practice to use them.

You can find more information about this here, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733040.aspx

Comment: NO I meant HTTPContext kind of support without use of ASPnetcompatibility mode on